# Iterate over a list of list, not returning all item from sub-list

Tags: python, iterator

I know I've seen clean examples on the proper way to do this, and could even swear it was in one of the standard python libraries. I can't seem to find it now. Could you please point me in the right direction.

Iterator for a list of lists that only returns arbitrary values from the sub-list. The idea is to have this in a list-comprehension.

```
alist = [    [1,2,3,4,5],
             [2,4,6,8,10],
             [3,6,9,12,15]    ]

only_some_values = [list(x[2]]) for x in alist]

[[3],[6],[9]]
```

But I am quite sure there is a function that does this same thing, but in iterator fashion, thus getting rid of my direct index access on the left side and chaining an additional iterator on the right side of the `for`. Perhaps it was a form of embedded list-comprehension, but I really thought there was a cleaner way (using imap maybe?).

Comment: Is `[[3],[6],[9]]` your expected output?

Comment: yes, the outer list needs to contain lists (for my application anyways)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you were thinking of `itemgetter`?

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(2), alist)
[3, 6, 9]
```

But that doesn't leave the elements in sublists

```
only_some_values = [[x[2]] for x in alist]
```

Gives your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had in mind:

```
from operator import itemgetter

alist = [    [1,2,3,4,5],
             [2,4,6,8,10],
             [3,6,9,12,15]    ]

[list(x) for x in zip(map(itemgetter(2),alist),
                      map(itemgetter(0),alist))    ]

[[3,1], [6,2], [9,3]]
```

The idea is that you keep the left side of the comprehension clean, probably replacing `list(x)` with another important call, and so it is easy to read where the first-level list elements are coming from.

I'm still not sure where I got this from, but its definitely not one of my original ideas.